# Route with FromBody doesn't work with ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying out ASP.NET Core MVC and cannot get a route working with a parameter marked with `[FromBody]`.  I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2 running on .NET Framework (full, not core).  Here's my entire controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EmailSch.Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("/api")]
    public class EmailJobController : ControllerBase
    {
        public EmailJobController() { }

        [Route("emailsch/job"), HttpPost]
        public IActionResult RunEmailJob([FromBody]string options)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

I try calling it from PowerShell using:

> > Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://localhost:9000/api/emailsch/job -Method Post -Body 'Hello there'

The result is:

> > Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

No exceptions are thrown in my code and no breakpoints are triggered.  If I remove the parameter:

```
public IActionResult RunEmailJob()
{
   return Ok("Hi");
}
```

It works fine.  Is there anything I need to setup in my Startup to get this to work?  Here's my entire Startup class:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvcCore();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got 500 Internal Server Error because you didn't specify any InputFormatters

At least one `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.IInputFormatter` is required to bind from the body.

To add json formatter use:

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters();
```

or add full MVC with default formatters

```
service.AddMvc();
```

then use

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://localhost:9000/api/emailsch/job -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Body 'Hello there'
```

Note: You'll also need to install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json` NuGet package.

Comment: You saved my life :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to have been of help @Sammy